# FGallery can not load ImagePath From NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, fgallery

See Below What I had done:

I have one `NSArray` which have 10 image paths, Which is directly fetched From my Local Database. Every Path is in this Format: `/Users/myname/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/CC5BE47A-8249-FDDF-90E3-415CEBGGD75AB/Documents/..`

I am using `FGallery` to display images in grid view and full size view. When I am trying to give the above `NSArray` to `FGallery` delegate method my application is getting crash.
and it give me the below Error:

```
***** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI pathExtension]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa4e8c70'
**
```

Now What I need is:

I need the solution of the above error and why my application is going to crash after initialize `NSArray` which have 10imagepaths into `FGallery` Delegate Method?

**Code added:**

```
 NSString *testString = (NSString *) [[self.allImageGalleryDetails valueForKey:@"imageGallery_Detail_ImagePath"]objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:testString, nil];
    listofImagePath = array; //Load FGallery View Controller 
    localGallery = [[FGalleryViewController alloc] initWithPhotoSource:self];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:localGallery animated:YES]; 
    [localGallery release];
```

Comment: NSString *testString = (NSString *) [[self.allImageGalleryDetails valueForKey:@"imageGallery_Detail_ImagePath"]objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:testString, nil];
 listofImagePath = array;
    
 //Load FGallery View Controller
localGallery = [[FGalleryViewController alloc] initWithPhotoSource:self];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:localGallery animated:YES];
[localGallery release];

Comment: where you are assigning the string to imageview?convert string into data after that pass that data to imageview .

Comment: i am assigning NSArray names listofImagePath which have around 10 NSString values to Fgallery Delegate Methods.

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this, instead of

```
  NSArray *imagesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Your_Path",...,nil];
```

use below line,

```
  NSArray *imagesArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"Your_Path"],..., nil];
```

in your case testString is your path,right? if so,then replace @"Your_Path" with testString.

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: First of all all image path are local path like:(/Users/myname/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/CC5BE47A-8249-FDDF-90E3-415CEBGGD75AB/Documents/)...

Comment: So use like [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/myname/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/CC5BE47A-8249-FDDF-90E3-415CEBGGD75AB/Documents/img.png"];

Comment: When i write as you type in above comment it will run without error. But when i write testString  as per my above example code. It gives me error.

Comment: if u will be  onine on skype it will be give me better help. My Skype id is: pranav.panchal30